# I have 6 values in array but when I execute, only 4 values are showed. why?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have 6 values in array `$arr1` but when I execute the code, only 4 values are shown, why?
The code finds that the maximum value is 526, but where I use `echo` to list the whole array the 526-valued array is not shown.

**Here is the code:**

```
<?php
$arr1[0][ ]=110;
$arr1[0][ ]=20;
$arr1[0][ ]=526;
$arr1[1][ ]=105;
$arr1[1][ ]=56;
$arr1[1][ ]=96;
echo "The given array is : <br>";
for($i=0;$i=count($arr1);$i++)
{
    for($j=0;$j=count($arr1);$j++)
    {
        Echo "\$arr1[$i][$j] =",$arr1[$i][$j],"<br>";
    }
}
$b=0;
foreach($arr1 as $val)
{
    foreach($val as $key=>$val1)
    {
        $b=$val1;
    }
}
Echo "The maximum value in the array is =",$b;
?>
```

Comment: `for($j=0;$j=count($arr1);$j++)` --> `for($j=0;$j=count($arr1[i]);$j++)`

Comment: The foreach works fine. Can't replicate the problem https://3v4l.org/X65rK

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with your code example.

The array `$arr1` has 2 entries with keys `0` and `1` so if you loop 2 times 2 values, you get 4 values instead of 6.

Then per key, there are 3 entries, so for the second loop you have to use `count($arr1[$i])` using `[$i]` to count the entries for that key.

In the loops, you are setting the value of `$i` to the count causing an infinite loop `$i=count($arr1)` while you have to use a `<` sign instead.

In the second part finding the largest value, you have to first check if the new value is greater than the current value, or else you will always have the last value.

```
$arr1[0][] = 110;
$arr1[0][] = 20;
$arr1[0][] = 526;
$arr1[1][] = 105;
$arr1[1][] = 56;
$arr1[1][] = 96;
echo "The given array is : <br>";
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr1); $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($arr1[$i]); $j++) {
        echo "\$arr1[$i][$j] =", $arr1[$i][$j], "<br>";
    }
}
$b = 0;
foreach ($arr1 as $val) {
    foreach ($val as $key => $val1) {
        if ($val1 > $b)
            $b = $val1;
    }
}
echo "The maximum value in the array is =", $b;
```

Output

```
The given array is :
$arr1[0][0] =110
$arr1[0][1] =20
$arr1[0][2] =526
$arr1[1][0] =105
$arr1[1][1] =56
$arr1[1][2] =96
The maximum value in the array is =526
```

See a [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/UP8BU)

---

As [@Nick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9473764/nick) points out, you could also compute the max in the nested for loops directly:

```
$b = 0;

echo "The given array is :" . PHP_EOL;
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr1); $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($arr1[$i]); $j++) {
        if ($arr1[$i][$j] > $b) $b = $arr1[$i][$j];
        echo "\$arr1[$i][$j] =", $arr1[$i][$j] . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/AQsvH)

Comment: It would seem you could just compute the max while you're outputting the values...

Comment: @Nick Yes that is of course also possible :-) I have updated the answer. I only focussed on the provided code by the OP.

Comment: Actually I *meant* compute the max in the nested `for` loops... :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can flatten the array by using `splat` operator then use `max`.

```
echo max(array_merge(...$arr1));
```

If you want you can use `implode` to print the values

```
 echo implode(' ',array_merge(...$arr1));
```

DEMO :- https://3v4l.org/0ZamG

Answer (score 0):

**Please use this code. I hope it will works for you.**

```
$arr1[0][ ]=110;
$arr1[0][ ]=20;
$arr1[0][ ]=526;
$arr1[1][ ]=105;
$arr1[1][ ]=56;
$arr1[1][ ]=96;
echo "The given array is : <br>";
for($i=0;$i<count($arr1);$i++)
{
   for($j=0;$j<count($arr1);$j++)
   {
       echo "$arr1[$i][$j] =",$arr1[$i][$j],"<br>";
   }
}
$b=0;
sort($arr1);
foreach($arr1 as $val)
{
    foreach($val as $key=>$val1)
    {
        $b=$val1;
    }
}

echo "The maximum value in the array is =",$b;
```